# WHM doesn't restore addon domains

Tags: whm, dedicated-server

When restoring a full backup of a domain from WHM it doesn't restore the addondomains or zonerecords
First I download remote transfer a full backup from old server to the new server.
Then from WHM I use Restore a Full Backup/cpmove File, it gets restored.
Website, emails, DB's all, except for addon domains and MX records.
Why is that?